# How recognize which UIImageview I've tapped?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to realize a sort of matrix editable by touch. 
A series of black or white cell that if tapped switch form black to withe or viceversa. 
For doing this i will use UIImageView arranged in stack view a Tap Gesture Recognizer. But how do I know which UIImageView was tapped? And in which way I can change the UIImage in the UIImageView?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are just white and black, it would be much simpler to use a `UIView` and set its `backgroundColor` to `.white` or `.black`.  You can use the `tag` property of the `UIView`s to identify them.

In your gestureRecognizer handler, the `recognizer.view` tells you the `view` that triggered the gesture.

You can assign the tags in *Interface Builder*.  For example, if you have an 8x8 array of squares, you could use a 2-digit number where the first digit is the row and the second digit is the column.  Thus, your tags would be `11`, `12`, ..., `87`, `88`.

```
func squareTapped(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        let tag = view.tag
        let row = tag / 10
        let col = tag % 10
        print("The view at row \(row), column \(col) was tapped")

        if view.backgroundColor == .black {
            view.backgroundColor = .white
        } else {
            view.backgroundColor = .black
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you do want to use images, then load the images as properties of your viewController and assign them based upon the row and column of your image.  Here I have used an *Outlet Collection* to hold all of the `UIImageView`s.  In *Interface Builder*, you'd connect each of your cells to the `squares` property.

```
class BoardViewController: UIViewController {
    let blackImage = UIImage(named: "blackImage")!
    let whiteImage = UIImage(named: "whiteImage")!
    @IBOutlet var squares: [UIImageView]!
    var recognizersAdded = false

    func setUpBoard() {
        for imageview in squares {
            if !recognizersAdded {
                let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(squareTapped))
                imageview.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
                imageview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            }

            let tag = view.tag
            let row = tag / 10
            let col = tag % 10

            // Just for demo purposes, set up a checkerboard pattern
            if (row + col) % 2 == 0 {
                imageview.image = blackImage
            } else {
                imageview.image = whiteImage
            }
        }
        recognizersAdded = true
    }

    func squareTapped(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let view = recognizer.view as? UIImageView {
            let tag = view.tag
            let row = tag / 10
            let col = tag % 10
            print("The view at row \(row), column \(col) was tapped")

            if view.image == blackImage {
                view.image = whiteImage
            } else {
                view.image = blackImage
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is that if I've two UIImage I need to add in Interface Builder two UITapGestureRecognizer, one for each UIImage and than connect the two UITapGestureRecognizer to the same IBAction. 
I'm new to swift... can you show how to implement your code in detail?

Comment: Each UIImageView does need its own UITapGestureRecognizer.  You can add them programmatically in the board setup routine. Be careful to only add them once. If board setup is run more than once, only add the gesture recognizes the first time. You can control that by having a Bool property in your VC which keeps track of whether they have been added. In Interface Builder, connect each of your UIImageViews to the squares IBOutlet collection and assign the tags.

Comment: A rookie mistake is to create one UITapGestureRecognizer and try to add that to multiple views. That won't work. Each view needs its own, so create the recognizer inside of the setup loop.

Comment: I updated the code to show the adding of the tap gesture recognizers.

Comment: Another question, how do you arrange in a matrix form the UIImage? I'm using stack...

Comment: Use nested StackViews. Put the UIImageViews of each row of the matrix in a StackView, and then group all of the rows into a StackView.

Comment: Do you think I can use UiPanGestureRecognizer to change colors of the UIView?

Answer (score 0):

Assign a tag to each UIImageView and Add Tap gestures on them.

Upon tap on any view , you can get the image view tapped by :

```
UIImageView *imageView = gestureRecogniser.view
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I'm using now is this, it works well.
But I want to use a pan gesture (UIPanGetureRecognizer) to change colors of the UIView. How can I do?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var PrincipalRowStack: UIStackView!

let rowsNumber=10
let colsNumber=10

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    super.viewDidLoad()

    var rowsStack = [UIStackView]()
    var images = [[UIView]]()
    var gestRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer]]()
    for r in 0...rowsNumber-1 {
        rowsStack.append(UIStackView())
        rowsStack[r].axis = .horizontal
        rowsStack[r].distribution = .fillEqually
        images.append([UIView]())
        gestRec.append([UITapGestureRecognizer]())
        for c in 0...colsNumber-1{
            images[r].append(UIView())
            gestRec[r].append(UITapGestureRecognizer())
            gestRec[r][c].addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.Tap(_:)))
            images[r][c].contentMode = .scaleToFill
            images[r][c].layer.borderWidth = 1
            images[r][c].layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.5, green:0.5, blue:0.5, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            images[r][c].addGestureRecognizer(gestRec[r][c])
            rowsStack[r].addArrangedSubview(images[r][c])
        }
    }
    for s in rowsStack{
        PrincipalRowStack.addArrangedSubview(s)
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func Tap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if let view = recognizer.view {
        //let tag = view.tag
        //let row = tag / 10
        //let col = tag % 10
        print("Tapped!")

        if view.backgroundColor == .black {
            view.backgroundColor = .white
        } else {
            view.backgroundColor = .black
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'solved adding a PanGestureRecognizer to the principalStackView and than i use this function with a hitTest to know which view should change color.

```
func pan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    if (recognizer.state == .began ||
        recognizer.state == .changed)
    {
        let loc = recognizer.location(in: principalRowStack)
        let view = principalRowStack.hitTest(loc, with: UIEvent())
        view?.backgroundColor = .black


    }

}
```